# Have @HostListener ignore when a modal is open on top of the component with listener?

Tags: angular

I'm using a host listener to listen for a key event. `@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])...` Is there some way to not listen for "window" but rather when that component is the top level component, i.e. if there is a modal open on top on the component with the host listener, I don't want to listen for the keyup.

```
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        if (this.isOpen) {
            this.escape.emit();
        }  
    }
}
```

EDIT: I use this in the modal component. But sometimes I have a modal open on top of a modal and I don't want to close all of them...

Comment: can you add more code. where is your `@HostListener` code is present in component or a directive? instead of `window:keyup` you should listen to `keyup` and place it inside a directive

Comment: in the component.

Comment: why is it in the component?

Comment: What do you mean by a directive?

Comment: Have a look at this [**documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

Comment: In that documentation it says a component is a directive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163514/discussion-between-aravind-and-zachscs).

Comment: I think you will have to create a shared service that hold the state of your modal "stack". When the keyup event fires with keyCode === 27 && this.isOpen === true && the modal is on top of the stack, close modal and remove from top of stack.

Comment: @LLai thanks, that's what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: Just got it @LLai I have a z index for each modal so I used a calculation and added that to the if statement

Comment: ah z-index. that is a good idea

Comment: @Zachscs can you look at my answer if you want to use `ngx-bootstrap`

Comment: I looked at it but I messaged you and told you I'm not using ngx-bootstrap so it's not really an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a better host listener target but just added an if statement that checks for the z value of the modal.

```
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {        
        if (this.isOpen && this.$modal[0].style.zIndex === (Modal.zIndex).toString()) {
            this.escape.emit();
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ngx-bootstrap` modal component you can use the `isShown` property and having `modal-component` as a `ViewChild` reference as below to achieve your result

```
@ViewChild('childModal') childModal :ModalDirective;


@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        if (!this.childModal.isShown) {
            console.log('something logged')
        }  
    }
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/bz8Am46Uk5D0F34xZC4k?p=preview)**